# Discord bot won't answer commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I just created a bot, doesn't do anything special, but it just won't answer commands.
I enable intents on the dev portal, I gave him admin privileges, the bot is online. It won't give me any error. Looking for something similar but it all ends up in something to do with the intents which I feel that they are right. This is the code:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, ActivityType } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
require("dotenv").config();

const mySecret = process.env['TOKEN']
const { setCommands } = require("./commands/help.js")
const { prefix } = require("./config.js");


const commands = {};

const client = new Client(
  {
    intents: [
      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
      GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
    partials: [
      Partials.Message,
      Partials.User,
      Partials.Channel,
      Partials.GuildMember
    ]
  });
// load commands
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  commands[command.name] = command;
}

setCommands(commands)

// login bot
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
  
  client.user.setActivity('Dimensions', {
    type: ActivityType.Listening
  })
});

client.on("message", message => {
  console.log(message)
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  let cmd = commands[command];
  if(cmd)
    cmd.execute(message, args)
});

client.login(mySecret);
```

This is the comand

```
module.exports = { 
  name: "ping",
  description: "Replies with 'pong'",
  execute: (message) => {
    message.channel.send("pong")
  }
}
```

This is my config file

```
module.exports = {
    prefix: "!"
  }
```

There is a help.js too where I set up some help commands with other commands, I don't think is relevant but I'll update it if it is. Also, this is running on replit, not sure if that matters?

Thankss

Comment: Are you sure it's an issue with messages and not with your command handler? Debug the handler and how they are assigned and executed

Comment: Just to confirm you are using the "old" approach with the message intent and a prefix and not the "new" Slash commands right? If you are using the Slash Commands ,  did you deploy the commands to your discord server?

Comment: I'll edit the question with the config file as I'm not sure if there is a specific way to do my commands

Answer (score -2):

You have to return the execute to execute the code:

```
module.exports = { 
   name: "ping",
   description: "Replies with 'pong'",
   execute: (message) => {
     return message.channel.send("pong")
   }
}
```

Comment: nope, that's not the issued, just tried

Comment: Make execute an async function?

Comment: nothing, I even tried to do the client.('message') async

Comment: Command functions can (and should be) void functions

Comment: Thank you, either way, the issue persists.